# Dimensional Models in Django

Tags: python, django, data-modeling

Django typically uses CRUD tables for it's data modelling.

Is it possible to create a dimensional model in django?

Example data for a given dimensional table could be:

| id | start_date | end_date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1999-02-28 | 2022-01-01 | VALUE1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-08-18 | VALUE2 |
| 1 | 2022-08-18 | 9999-12-31 | VALUE3 |

Comment: Probably you mean *temporal* tables. Try using this word for searching answers.

Comment: If you work with model admin - those table is Django admin log

Comment: I think you're misusing the term 'dimensional model' here, but you can absolutely build models that have date ranges associated with data. Even better, if using Postgres as your database, you can use DateTimeRangeField to store the range in a single field and get the benefits of easier range queries (identifying overlaps, etc)